# How can I connect celery container to rabbitmq container when using --net=host?

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

I can not connect my celery container to rabbitmq container when using --net=host.

I start my rabbitmq with:

```
docker run -d --rm --net=host --hostname=rabbitmq --name=rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=donald -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=duck rabbitmq-mgnt
```

my rabbitmq server is defined in DNS:

```
nslookup amqp
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Name:   amqp.service.consul
Address: 10.68.32.180
```

I can connect and verify credentials:

```
curl -i -u donald:duck http://amqp:15672/api/whoami
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
vary: Accept-Encoding, origin
Server: MochiWeb/1.1 WebMachine/1.10.0 (never breaks eye contact)
Date: Mon, 27 Feb 2017 20:51:12 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 41
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

But I fail to connect with celery:

```
docker run -d --rm --net=host --hostname=celery --name=celery celery
a52019dbe491926dc28937859c33503db211c79536256a5e8d652e72e6198639
```

docker logs celery

```
[2017-02-27 20:53:59,979: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://donald:**@amqp:5672//: [Errno -2] Name or service not known.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...
```

Have I missed something?

Kind Regards
Mathias

Comment: Why not `docker network create celery-rabbitmq`  and then launch your 2 containers in this network? Your rabbitmq should be a container though

Comment: I wanted it simple since I have many caontainers and vm who need to talk to eachother and therefore use --net=host.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason.
I had forgotten to add localhost as nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf in celery container.

Thanks for your time.
Mathias